# Can't execute python scripts, permission denied?

Tags: python

I'm trying to compile a project using "appcelerator" (crossplatform dev for iphone/android). Just evaluating it. It seems to run some python scripts to do the build, but can't get it to work (and not getting anywhere on the help forums there). Seems like a permissions error, but I can't figure it out. Thought I'd try here in case this is a familiar thing in python:

```
Exception occured while building project:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.2/android/builder.py", line 2089, in <module>
     s.build_and_run(True, avd_id, device_args=device_args)
   File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.2/android/builder.py", line 1934, in build_and_run
     run_result = run.run(dex_args, warning_regex=r'warning: ')
   File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.8.2/android/run.py", line 36, in run
     process = subprocess.Popen(args, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
     errread, errwrite)
   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
     raise child_exception
 OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I've set the permissions for "run.py" and "builder.py" to 777. The "subprocess.py" file also is 777. I'm still getting the permission denied error. Is there something obvious I'm missing here? I'm an admin user, on os 10.6.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code you were trying to execute.

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod 777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't in any of the python files you mention, but in whatever command that should be executed by the `subprocess.Popen` statement.

To troubleshoot the problem you can try to use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) to debug the problem or just edit `run.py` and add:

```
print args
```

just before `subprocess.Popen` to figure out what's the command for which there aren't enough permissions.

Comment: Ah awesome thanks, I printed out what that function was trying to call as you suggested, seems it was trying to execute a script in the android sdk that didn't have the right permissions. Changed on that file and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer @jcollado! In my case it was [path to android sdk]/android-sdk-linux/tools/zipalign that didn't have the right permissions. `sudo chmod 777 zipalign` did the trick for me on Titanium 2.0.2GA